# SFMC Push notification to run ampscript contentblock by id and SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, mobilepush

I want to send a push notification to add points to an external system via an api call to mulesoft.
The push notification is sent via the journey that is triggered via an api call.

I have a content block that works in the email, however, when I use the same block in the push notification the points are not added.

I have checked and all the variables are passed correctly however as part of the content block I am calling via contentblockbyid + lookup to a data extension to retrieve block id the below block.

Is the issue that SSJS cannot be run in a push notification?

Push notification:
retrieve subscriber Key,
set points
set account id
contentblockbyid(@script)

the content block by id calls:

- uses ampscript to set the subscriberkey and points
- call mulesoft using ssjs

```
    %%[
     /*
     This is an example what should be added before this code snippet in a message.
     SET @PointsToAdd = 100
     SET @Reason = "Bonus from SFMC"
     SET @ActionID = "100" (optional)
     */
    ]%%
    
    %%[a
        set @debug = false
        SET @SubscriberKey = _subscriberkey
        IF Empty(_subscriberKey) THEN
          SET @SubscriberKey = @ContactKey
        ENDIF
        
        SET @AccountId = Lookup("Local_Contacts", "AccountId", "ContactKey", @SubscriberKey)
        
    ]%%
    <script runat="server">
      Platform.Load("Core","1");
      
      /*  IF THIS IS NOT THE FINAL RENDER FOR FOR SEND - STOP FUNCTION.*/
      
      var actionID = Variable.GetValue("ActionID")
      var legalEntity = Variable.GetValue("LegalEntity")
      if(actionID == "" || actionID == null) {
        actionID = "100"
      }
      
      /* PASS DATA FROM AMPSCRIPT TO SSJS*/
      var data = {
          accountId: Variable.GetValue("@AccountId"),
          pointsToAdd: Variable.GetValue("@PointsToAdd"),
          reason: Variable.GetValue("@Reason")
      }
      
      /*´API CONFIGURATION */
        var config = {
          url : "https://*****/"+ data.accountId + "/points",
          contentType : "application/json",
          headerName : ["client_id", "client_secret", "loyaltyBackendId"],
          headerValue : ["*****", "*****", legalEntity],
          payload : {
            "actionId": actionID,
            "activity": "CREDIT",
            "reason": data.reason,
            "amount": data.pointsToAdd
          }
        }
        try{
          var content = [0];
            var statusCode = Platform.Function.HTTPPost(config.url,config.contentType,Stringify(config.payload),config.headerName,config.headerValue,content);
          if (statusCode == 202)  {
              /*Platform.Response.Write(content[0]);*/
         }
          Variable.SetValue("@annexResponse", statusCode)
      } catch(e) {
        Write(Stringify(config));
          Write(Stringify(e));
        }
    </script>
    %%[IF @debug THEN]%%
    annexResponse:%%=v(@annexResponse)=%%
    MessageContext:%%=v(@MessageContext)=%%
    SubscriberKey:%%=v(@SubscriberKey)=%%
    AccountId:%%=v(@AccountId)=%%
    %%[ENDIF]%%
```

Comment: Where are you setting @ContactKey? _subscriberKey is an email function that will only work if the person exists in the All Subscribers list. Is your only issue here that the API call doesn't appear to be made? Do you get the right output with all the correct data in SubscriberKey, AccountId etc?

Comment: Hi @JarrettBush - yes just the points assigned via API are not assigned, the subscriberkey is passed via another script, and when I call the variables in the Push I can see them.

Comment: Gotta be honest - I've never tried an SSJS block in a push notification, however I would be more inclined to think that your issue is the ContentBlockById call rather than the SSJS. If you strip out this code from the content block and put it in the body of the push notification, does it work?